# Circumconic with $\angle(ABP)=\angle(ACP)$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In $\triangle ABC$, define $\{P\mid \angle ABP= \angle PCA\}$.

Since it is the isogonal conjugate of the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, i.e. $\{P\mid \angle BPC= \angle PCB\}$, I know that it is a rectangular hyperbola centered at $M$, the midpoint of $BC$.

So first, I wonder is there a name for the curve? Second, what are the some special points it passes?

Comment: It passes through the vertices and through the orthocenter.

Comment: And it belongs to a wider family of hyperbolae: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420131/prove-that-a-conic-section-through-the-vertices-of-a-triangle-and-its-orthocentr