# Three properties of a parabola with three tangents

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

About ten days ago I discovered three beautiful properties of a parabola with three tangents drawn using the GeoGebra program. I would like to get proof of these properties and also know if any of them have been discovered before or not.

[image]

We have a parabola, and we chose three points from it, $A$, $B$, and $C$. We drew the tangents to the parabola in them, which enclose the triangle $∆MNP$, so the area of triangle ABC will be equal to twice the area of triangle $∆MNP$.
In other words $T=2S$

Another beautiful property is achieved in the form:
$\frac{FA×FB×FC}{FM×FN×FP}=1$

Also, the lines $AN$, $BM$, and $CP$ converge at one point

[image]

Comment: The first property is known : see [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/prove-that-the-area-of-the-triangle-formed-by-three-points-on-a-parabola-is/). I didn't know the second property nor the third.

Comment: A little remark : you don't need figure 1. Figure 2 is enough.

Comment: A result that could be helpful : [Lambert's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3704407/305862) asserting that the circumcircle of triangle MNP passes through focus $F$.

Comment: Another useful result : the fact that the orthocenter of triangle $MNP$ belongs to the directrix of the parabola can be found in this answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3506121/305862).

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I know Lambert's theorem, but I did not know that the first property was previously discovered, but it is expected because it is an elementary property of the parabola

Comment: I wonder if the opposite is true. What if we were looking for the locus that satisfies the property that the area of ​​its triangle is equal to twice the area of ​​the tangent triangle? Would we get a parabola or would the locus be larger than that?

Comment: The third property appears to be general to all conic sections

Comment: It suffices then to prove the third property for a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the third property in the special case of a circle: as projective transformations preserve collinearity, the result holds for any conic section.

The proof follows from the converse of Ceva's theorem applied to triangle $PMN$: lines $PC$, $AN$, $BM$ concur if:

$$
{BN\over BP}\cdot{AP\over AM}\cdot{CM\over CN}=1.
$$
But that is trivially true, because
$$
BN=CN,\quad BP=AP,\quad AM=CM.
$$

[image]